# Number of solutions with Hamming weight $w$ in an random undetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $Ax=y$ a random undetermined linear system over $\mathbb{F}_2$, where $A\in \mathbb{F}_2^{m × n}$ and $y\in \mathbb{F}_2^m$.How many solutions have, with high probability, number of ones $p$?

Comment: IMHO this is an unanswerable question. Depends on the method of choice of $A$ and $y$. For all we know the solution space could be empty. If the solution space is a coset of a subspace of dimension $k$, and then the expected number of weight $p$ vectors in such a set is $2^{k-n}\binom n p$. But this is probably a meaningless number for your purposes.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what is the probability of the solution space is a coset of a subspace of dimension $k$ in an random linear system?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen there is some method to construct a random undetermined linear system where the solution space is a coset of a subspace of dimension $k$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you help me please?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I found answers in literature for my questions in the comments. But I do not found any information about your last claim "the expected number of weight $p$ vector in such a set is $2^{k-n}\binom{n} {p}$"